# prevent variable hoisting in Python

Tags: python

In Python, I want to prevent my local variable to be hoisted to the parent scope. Basically, I want to avoid accidental programming errors by keeping the variable b's scope local to the 'if' block. Is it possible in Python. How?

```
a = 10
if a == 10:
    b = 5
else:
    c = 0

print b
# prints 5
```

Comment: There is no variable hoisting going on. The `if` block does not create a scope. Everything in your code is in the global scope.

Comment: Ok, to clarify my question further: Is it possible by any means (knowing the default scoping rules in Python) to limit the visibility of  variable 'b' to the immediate containing block.

Comment: No, python does not have block scope. You could borrow a common JavaScript idiom which is to create and immediately invoke a function